# Drawing ellipsis in networks in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I have the following basic code. I need to draw a network as follows. Can someone amend this code for me?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption, pgf, tikz,geometry, hyperref}
\geometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
\centering  

\begin{tikzpicture}[
> = stealth, % arrow head style
shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
auto,
node distance = 3cm, % distance between nodes
semithick % line style
]

\tikzstyle{every state}=[
draw = black,
thick,
fill = white,
minimum size = 4mm
]
\node (a) {...};
\node[state] (b) at ($ (a) + (0:2) $) {m};
\node (a0)  at ($ (b) + (90:1) $) {};
\node (c) at ($ (b) + (0:2) $) {...};
\node[state] (d) at ($ (a) + (-45:1.5) $) {j};
\node[state] (e) at ($ (b) + (-45:1.5) $) {k};
\node[state] (f) at ($ (d) + (-45:1.5) $) {i};

\path[] (a) edge node {$\dots$} (b);
\path[] (b) edge node {$\vdots$} (a0);
\path[->] (a) edge node {} (d);
\path[->] (b) edge node {} (d);
\path[->] (b) edge node {} (e);
\path[->] (c) edge node {} (e);
\path[->] (d) edge node {} (f);
\path[->] (e) edge node {} (f);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Assembly topology with diamond}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

**My result** is:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I think your result and your image are quiet the same. What is missing? Do you need ellipsis instead of circles?

Comment: Thanks @Bobyandbob. I do not want the lines next to $m$. I want the dots at the same location as my handmade figure.

Comment: Replace `\path[] (a) edge node {$\dots$} (b);
\path[] (b) edge node {$\vdots$} (a0);` with `\node (nord) at ($ (b) + (90:0.7) $) {\vdots};` You could use`\node (a) {\dots};` instead of `\node (a) {...};`.

Answer (score 4):

`edge` command draws a line by default, if you don't want it use `edge[draw=none]`. But this option won't draw dots where you want.

As an alternative solution I propose following code. It shows some changes respect the original one:

- it uses `every state/.style` instead of `\tikzstyle`. See: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)
- it uses `positioning` library instead of `calc` related coordinates.
- dots are drawn as regular nodes.

The result looks like:

[image]

And the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption, pgf, tikz,geometry, hyperref}
\geometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
\centering  

\begin{tikzpicture}[
> = stealth, % arrow head style
shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
auto,
node distance = 3cm, % distance between nodes
semithick, % line style
every state/.style={
    draw = black,
    thick,
    fill = white,
    minimum size = 4mm
}
]

\node (a) {\dots};
\node[state, right=2cm of a] (b) {m};
\node[right=2cm of b] (c) {\dots};
\node[above=1mm of b] {\vdots};
\node[state, below left=1cm and 1cm of b] (d) {j};
\node[state, below right=1cm and 1cm of b] (e) {k};
\node[state, below right=1cm and 1cm of d] (f) {i};

\path[->] (a) edge node {} (d);
\path[->] (b) edge node {} (d);
\path[->] (b) edge node {} (e);
\path[->] (c) edge node {} (e);
\path[->] (d) edge node {} (f);
\path[->] (e) edge node {} (f);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Assembly topology with diamond}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```